# Where should I download the Samsung galaxy pro PC suite?

Tags: nokia-pc-suite

Where should I download the Samsung galaxy pro PC suite? Please tell me. I cannot find it

Comment: Did you try the Samsung website?

Comment: A couple of searches on the G-box (Google that is) will give you the ans, I'd imagine.

Answer (score 1):

Try Samsung's [website](http://www.samsungapps.com). It had the Kies software for my Galaxy S